# How do I setup Oracle ODBC drivers on RHEL 6/Linux

Tags: linux, oracle, odbc, drivers, rhel6

I need to setup Oracle ODBC drivers on RHEL 6 to connect to an Oracle data source residing on a remote Windows machine.

I have taken the following steps:
[1] Installed oracle-instanceclient-basic
[2] Set environment variables: ORACLE_HOME and LD path
[3] Created /etc/oracle/TNSnames.ora and configured but it did not set it correctly

Initially, I got the error, `"Connect failed because target or object does not exist"`

Then, I set: `ORACLE_SID = DB_NAME` in the TNSnames.ora file.

But, that did not fix the issue, I got a new error message now: `"TNS: net service name is incorrectly specified"`

Comment: So what's not working for you?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
yum install unixODBC
rpm -ivh oracle-instantclient-basic-10.2.0.3-1.i386.rpm #downloaded on http://www.oracle.com/technology/software/tech/oci/instantclient/htdocs/linuxsoft.html
unzip instantclient-odbc-linux32-10.2.0.3-20061115.zip #downloaded on http://www.oracle.com/technology/software/tech/oci/instantclient/htdocs/linuxsoft.html
cp ./instantclient_10_2/libsqora.so.10.1 /usr/lib/oracle/10.2.0.3/client/lib/
export ORACLE_HOME=/usr/lib/oracle/10.2.0.3/client
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:$ORACLE_HOME/lib
```

Also you need to set `$TWO_TASK` (default location where Oracle is looking to pickup the server) to point to where the Oracle server is running on Windows - - don't forget to add the listener at the end after the port number:

```
export TWO_TASK=//213.123.23.19:1521/listener
```

To chech for the name of listener, type the following commands on the windows prompt that is running the Oracle server:

```
lsnrctl
status
```

It will enlist listeners and their state (READY or UNKNOWN). Connect to the listener that is in the ready state: `Instance "zelistener", status READY`

mkdir /etc/oracle

vi /etc/oracle/tnsnames.ora

```
MY_SID =
 ( DESCRIPTION =
  (ADDRESS_LIST =
  (ADDRESS =
  (PROTOCOL = TCP)
  (Host = 127.0.0.1)
  (Port = 1521)
  )
 )
 (CONNECT_DATA = (SID = MY_SID)
 )
)
```

export TNS_ADMIN=/etc/oracle

vi /etc/odbcinst.ini

```
[OracleODBC-10g]
Description = Oracle ODBC driver for Oracle 10g
Driver = /usr/lib/oracle/10.2.0.3/client/lib/libsqora.so.10.1
FileUsage = 1
Driver Logging = 7
```

vi /etc/odbc.ini

```
[simple]
Driver = OracleODBC-10g
DSN = OracleODBC-10g
ServerName = MY_SID
UserID = USER
Password = PASSWORD
```

isql -v simple

```
+---------------------------------------+
| Connected!                            |
|                                       |
| sql-statement                         |
| help [tablename]                      |
| quit                                  |
|                                       |
+---------------------------------------+
```

Comment: I guess updated links for driver download is http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/linuxx86-64soft-092277.html

Answer (score 2):

I think that we should assign the version of unixODBC.
if to connect the oracle12c, we should use the unixODBC-2.3.1

Comment: As you said, It seems that the unixODBC 2.2.14 provided by RH is not compatible with Oracle Driver above the 10.x and need to be upgrade.